# What to add in settings.py to use mangoengine + Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm using Django 1.9 and I would like to use it with mongodb. I saw different ways to do it, most of them require to downgrade to Django 1.6 at most. I found a last one with mongoengine [enter link description here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/django.html). However, there is only documentation to use it with pymongon and no indication for Django. I can't find any documentation on the web neither. Did anyone succeed to use mongoengine with Django ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Django MongoDB Engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: the problem with mangoDB Engine is that it needs Django-nonrel which is not up to date (the last one is based on Django 1.6) and thus lacks of many features. I need to use Django 1.9.

Comment: My (quick) search didn't yield anything specifically for Django 1.9 except for this GitHub project (https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) that's working on a 1.9-compatible engine.  Maybe lend a hand to get them up to speed if you're capable.

Comment: As mcjoejoe said, it turned out mangoengine is no more supported with new django releases. Only django-nonrel can do the thing. It's so bad, I don't really understand why it is not supported anymore.